# changing default view of input type month

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

i am using input[type='month'] to get expiration date from user. it usually appears like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to show to the user like this: [![enter image description here][2]][2]

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Input masking. This is a simple code with which you can mask the input without jQuery or any other plugin. The JS file takes very less space compared to other plugins. [Refer here for more details.](https://github.com/estelle/input-masking)

```css
input,input:hover,input:focus{
  font-family: monospace;
  border-width:0px;
border:none;
width:60px;
outline: none;
}
label {
  display: inline;
}
div {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.shell {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1; }
  
  .shell span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 1px;
    color: #ccc;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1; }
    
.shell span i {
      font-style: normal;
      /* any of these 3 will work */
      color: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden; }

input.masked,
.shell span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase; }
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/masking-input.js" data-autoinit="true"></script>

<label for="cc">Expiry Date:</label>
<input id="cc" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" class="masked" pattern="(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(1[5-9]|2\d)" data-valid-example="05/18"/>
```